# How could I recruit neurodiverse participants on a user testing platform?

Tags: usability, user-research, usability-testing, usability-study, recruitment

I already test designs for accessibility with users of screen readers, magnifiers and switch navigation. We recruit for this through a platform called Fable, which is specific to testers who use assistive technologies.

I am starting to think about how we might recruit test participants who are autistic or severely dyslexic or have some other neuroatypical condition. These people may not use an assistive technology but may have specific usability needs that neurotypical users don't have.

What is the best way to write screening questions to recruit neurodiverse participants on UserTesting.com (or another similar platform)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience with this myself, but because there are organisations and advocacy groups for these user groups, perhaps it is a more direct way to just approach them about contacting people who might be interested in participating or have them put out the expression of interest instead. And they will also be able to provide some advice on how to conduct the testing by taking into consideration specific needs that these user groups might have.

I actually don't think many of the online user recruitment platforms will have the capability to provide the necessary support to collect test data adequately for these types of users, hence you probably should look at alternate ways of doing user testing.